# React Passing props to new URL/route

Tags: reactjs, url, routes

I'm fairly new to React and can't figure out how to do something fairly simple (I'd assume).  I would like to pass props to a new URL that is clicked on from a chart element (it has to be this element).

I have a chart on a page that I've assigned a click event to.

```
 <div id='plotlyContainer' className='dashboard-border-container'>
        { 
          toDrilldown &&
          <Redirect to={{
              pathname: '/portfolio/drilldown',
              state: {
                filters: this.props.filters,
                category: this.props.category,
                chartType: this.props.chartType
              }
            }}
          />
        }
        <Plot
          data={this.props.data}
          layout={this.props.layout}
          useResizeHandler={true}
          style={{width: '100%', height: '100%'}}
          onClick={this.navigateToDrillDownPage.bind(this)}
        />
      </div>
```

click event:

```
navigateToDrillDownPage() {
    this.setState({toDrilldown: true})
 }
```

How do I  pass the  filters, category and chartType props to the new URL (drillDownURL)?

Comment: Are you using `react-router`?

Comment: @cubrr we're using react-router-dom

Comment: In that case you don't want to use `window.location`, but use React Router's methods for redirection, which allow you to pass data through `state`. See its documentation for examples: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, so I figured it might help others.  The redirect state object was undefined until I wrapped my component at (portfolio/drilldown) with:

```
export default withRouter(PortDrillDownContainer)
```

After wrapping, the state objected had all the values I expected.